# Update php generated content without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've created a php function (called "category_page" in "category-page.php") which reads data from a file into an associative array and then generates some html to display the information on products.php (the page calling the "category_page" function)

My aim is to allow the user to select from a drop down in order to sort the displayed information without refreshing the page.

I have so far managed to achieve this using `document.formname.submit` on change of the dropdown and then using `$_GET` to choose which key in the array to sort by, however, this causes the page to reload.

I have a *little* knowledge of php, javascript/jquery and have done a fair bit of searching/reading on AJAX to enable an update without refresh/reload, but can't seem to put all the pieces together.

So, in products.php, I have the following javascript/jquery:

```
function sort_products() {
queryString = "?sort_list="+$("#sort_list").val();
$.ajax({   
    type: 'GET',                                   
    url: 'category-page.php',         
    data: 'sort_list='+queryString
})
}

$("#sort_list").on("change", function() { sort_products() });
```

and then in category-page.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['sort_list'])) {
    $sort = $_GET['sort_list'];
} 
else {
    // set default sort order
}
```

I've verified in Chrome's network panel that a request for `category-page.php?sort_list=price` is being sent, but the page isn't updating. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code:

```
$("#sort_list").on("change", function(e) { sort_products(); e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the query is sent, you need to make something with what is returned.

```
$.ajax({   
    type: 'GET',                                   
    url: 'category-page.php',         
    data: 'sort_list='+queryString
})
.done(function(data) {
    // if your php code returns the html you can make something like this
    // the var data will be the html code
    $('#your-container').html(data)
})
```